# How to write on a focused NSTextfield (outside my App) after a Global Monitor for an Event is triggered?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, textfield, keyboard-events

I'm creating an OSX App that listens for global events (key down), using

```
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask handler:^(NSEvent *event){       
     //execute this code when keys are pressed
}];
```

and I want to perform something like this, for example:
I'm on safari (or any other app), typing on a textfield, and I press the keys 'hhh'. My App receives a notification that those keys were pressed and it writes 'Hello' on the textfield that I was typing on.

So, how do i know that the keys 'hhh' were pressed by the user while typing on a textfield and how can i write, programmaticaly, 'hello' to that textfield? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessibility framework (and assistive devices as suggested in another answer) does not provide anything useful here. It allows you to manipulate windows on the screen, but not their internal view hierarchy (and that includes NSTextField).

You have 2 options here: you can either use SIMBL or AppleScript. You have a lot more flexibility with SIMBL when it comes to manipulating elements, so I'd recommend going with that. SIMBL allows you to compile "tweak" libraries that are then loaded into apps of your choice, effectively allowing you to override application behavior and add functionality.

You can either continue detecting global keypress events in your app, and use IPC/XPC to communicate with your "tweak" library and inform it to modify the current active NSTextField, or if you don't need central management you can just put this logic in the tweak itself.

The focused NSTextField will be the `-firstResponder` in the NSResponder chain

For more info regarding SIMBL, you can go [here](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php), or if you want to use AppleScript, here's some info related to generating system (including keypress) events in other apps: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/AppleScript_Programming/System_Events

Comment: but with SIMBL do i need to make a tweak for each app i wanna work with? isn't there an easier method, without external tweaks, (using just code inside my App) so i can find out what textfield the user is writing on (the first responder of the foremost window) and write again, programmatically, to that same textfield?

Comment: You can make a general tweak that loads into all Cocoa/AppKit apps. Since the NSResponder logic is the same, you can probably use the same code everywhere (i.e. compile one tweak, and tell SIMBL to load it into everything).

Comment: btw, is that app store friendly?

Comment: definitely not App Store friendly :P

Answer (score 0):

From memory I believe you can do this, but you'll need to enable the "Enable access for assitive devices" in system prefs. Then what you describe should be doable. If you don't do this, you'll not receive any events on the global handler.

Comment: but how can i input text on the selected textfield (any textfield, from any app but mine) ?